# How do I suggest migrating a question from here to another SE site?

Tags: discussion

[Playing Risk in an arbitrary graph](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5437/playing-risk-in-an-arbitrary-graph)

Looks like it might be more appropriate on the theoretical computer science stack exchange site.

What's the process for suggesting these types of moves?

Comment: Please notice that in this case this question is completely off-topic for [cstheory.se]: We welcome *research-level* questions in *theoretical computer science*.

Comment: Game theory and Graph Theory combined?  Are you saying Mathematics is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flag it and the responding moderator could do it. This will normally involve the moderator talking to the mods of the destination site to see if they agree with the proposed move.  This can take some time to resolve.